# detect touch/ "mousePressed" on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, mousedown

I want to hide a image when the screen get's touched and show it again when the user doesn't touch the screen anymore.
At the moment i have this:

```
$('#patternFrame').mousedown(function() {
    $("#patternImage").hide();
})
```

It works great on a desktop. But on the iPad the mousedown event get's triggered when i stop touching the screen. So it reacts more like a mouse up now.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: did you try .hover() ? http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').on('touchstart', function(){

});
```